# Piranha CMS Manager Users other than the Admin

Tags: piranha-cms

On Piranha CMS manager, simply adding a new user using the UI does not allow that new user to log in. How do I get the new users to work on the manager login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I added the admin permission to the role I added the user to, I was able to log into the manager with my newly created user with the permissions I granted.